# Update sub-index when inserting in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-insert

I have a table that simplified looks like this:

```
group   index    value
1       1        text 1
1       2        text 2
1       3        text 3
2       1        text 4
2       2        text 5
2       3        text 6
```

Group is an foreign key that is also used for grouping items in the table.

Index is an internal index for sorting the items within the group.

Text is just a value.

Then if I do an insert or running a stored procedure to do the insert

```
INSERT INTO Table VALUES (1, 2, 'new text')
```

I would like to update the index for the group 1 items so the table looks like this:

```
group   index    value
1       1        text 1
1       2        new text (inserted)
1       3        text 2   (index updated)
1       4        text 3   (index updated)
2       1        text 4
2       2        text 5
2       3        text 6
```

(Running on MS SQL-Server 2008)

Comment: What when user deletes record/update one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a store procedure you can use.  Takes 3 parameters, grp, idx, and value:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE ReIndex
@grp int,
@idx int,
@value nvarchar(30)
AS
IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM [tbl] WHERE grp = @grp and idx =@idx)
INSERT INTO tbl VALUES (@grp, @idx, @value)
else
update tbl
set idx = idx+1
where
grp =@grp and
idx >= @idx

INSERT INTO tbl VALUES (@grp, @idx, @value)
```

Usage:

```
exec reindex 1, 2, 'new text'
```

sqlfiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/3323d/11

Comment: Brilliant answer! I'm going to bookmark this for the future!

Answer (score 0):

In this answer I'll assume the first column names are *grp* and *idx*, as *group* and *index* are reserved words in SQL.

You can use the next available *idx* value by using a `MAX(idx)+1` formula, like this:

```
INSERT INTO t1(grp, idx, value)
SELECT 1, IFNULL(MAX(idx),0)+1, 'new text'
FROM   t1
WHERE  grp = 1;
```

But this way two records inserted at about the same time might get the same *idx* value. To avoid this you could lock your table while inserting the record. You can do that by wrapping the above statement with table lock/unlock statements:

```
LOCK TABLES t1;
...
UNLOCK TABLES;
```

However, this method cannot be used within procedures. There the solution involves creating a transaction, and a `SELECT ... FOR UPDATE`. Note that you need [InnoDB Storage](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/innodb-storage-engine.html) for this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE ins_val(IN pgrp int, IN pvalue varchar(200)) 
BEGIN
    DECLARE newidx INT;
    START TRANSACTION;

        SELECT IFNULL(MAX(idx),0)+1
        INTO   newidx
        FROM   t1
        WHERE  grp = pgrp;
        FOR UPDATE;

        INSERT INTO t1(grp, idx, value)
        VALUES (pgrp, newidx, pvalue);

    COMMIT;
END;
```

Note that if you later delete records, these will leave gaps in the *idx* numbering that will not be filled again by the above method. On the other hand, if the records with the highest *idx* value is deleted, the next inserted record will re-use that *idx* value.